# Is the order preserved when inserting into multiple tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I have 3 tables created and there is no foreign key, so they are not related to each other.
In my program, I use JDBC to interact with DB. Now I have a query to insert into each of the table at once:

```
insert into table1 values (...);
insert into table2 values (...);
insert into table3 values (...);
```

Can I expect that the insert statements will be executed in order, and then completed in order?
In another word, can I expect table1 to have the inserted row first, then table2, and finally table3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your program's perspective the inserts will be executed in order.

From outside of your transaction, the inserts will appear simultaneously when your transaction is committed.